# $E(x\mid xy)$ linear in $xy$

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation

I read a paper that makes an assumption that $E(x\mid xy)$ linear in $xy$ where $x$ and $y$ are independent.

I was wondering what is fundamental about this assumption, or in other words, what specifics about the density function do we assume to get this linearity.

Thank you!

Comment: The assumption is more a modeling specification than a mathematical justification. Since $E(X|XY) = f(XY)$ for some Borel measurable function $f$, I guess the author just specify $f$ to be linear so that it is easier to handle or derive some properties. (as in linear model, we specify the conditional expectation $E(Y|X)$ to be a linear function of $X$). I didn't really see how the independence between $X$ and $Y$ came into play.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the distributions of $x$ and $y$ and what is the source of the question?